# Remove duplicate lines containing same starting text

Tags: regex, replace, duplicates, notepad++

So I have a massive list of numbers where all lines contain the same format.

```
#976B4B|B|0|0
#970000|B|0|1
#974B00|B|0|2
#979700|B|0|3
#4B9700|B|0|4
#009700|B|0|5
#00974B|B|0|6
#009797|B|0|7
#004B97|B|0|8
#000097|B|0|9
#4B0097|B|0|10
#970097|B|0|11
#97004B|B|0|12
#970000|B|0|13
#974B00|B|0|14
#979700|B|0|15
#4B9700|B|0|16
#009700|B|0|17
#00974B|B|0|18
#009797|B|0|19
#004B97|B|0|20
#000097|B|0|21
#4B0097|B|0|22
#970097|B|0|23
#97004B|B|0|24
#2C2C2C|B|0|25
#979797|B|0|26
#676767|B|0|27
#97694A|B|0|28
#020202|B|0|29
#6894B4|B|0|30
#976B4B|B|0|31
#808080|B|1|0
#800000|B|1|1
#803F00|B|1|2
#808000|B|1|3
```

What I am trying to do is remove all duplicate lines that contain the same hex codes, regardless of the text after it.

Example, in the first line `#976B4B|B|0|0` the hex #976B4B shows up in line 32 as `#976B4B|B|0|31`. I want all lines EXCEPT the first occurrence to be removed.

I have been attempting to use regex to solve this, and found `^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$` `$1` can remove duplicate lines but obviously not what I need. Looking for some guidance and maybe a possibility to learn from this.

Comment: There are many questions here in Stack Overflow asking very similar questions. Please do a search for `[notepad++] remove duplicate is:q`. One of those will surely help you. If not then please explain what is different and special about this case.

Comment: To do this in one pass you need a regex flavor that supports variable length lookbehind, e.g. .NET regex. You can paste your str in Regexstorm and try [`(?m)^#(\w+)\b(?<=^#\1[\s\S]+?\b).+\n?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%5e%23%28%5cw%2b%29%5cb%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%23%5c1%5b%5cs%5cS%5d%2b%3f%5cb%29.%2b%5cn%3f&i=%23976B4B%7cB%7c0%7c0%0d%0a%23970000%7cB%7c0%7c1%0d%0a%23976B4B%7cB%7c0%7c0%0d%0a%23970000%7cB%7c0%7c1&r=) (check the "replace matches with", click on context for result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex replacement, make sure you click <kbd>Replace All</kbd> as many times as necessary, until no match is found:

**Find What**: `^((#[[:xdigit:]]+)\|.*(?:\R.+)*?)\R\2\|.*` 
**Replace With**: `$1`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DZwIHW/1) and the demo screenshot:

[image]

*Details*:

- `^`  - start of a line
- `((#[[:xdigit:]]+)\|.*(?:\R.+)*?)` - Group 1 (`$1`, it will be kept):

  - `(#[[:xdigit:]]+)` - Group 2: `#` and one or more hex chars
  - `\|` - a `|` char
  - `.*` - the rest of the line
  - `(?:\R.+)*?` - any zero or more non-empty lines (if they can be empty, replace `.+` with `.*`)
- `\R\2\|.*` - a line break, Group 2 value, `|` and the rest of the line.